# Exponential limits for C and Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, floating-accuracy, digits

In computers, the math operation of floating numbers is actually processed using the base number and the exponential number separately, and then combine them together. We learn this in our computation fundamental textbooks. However, I find the limits in C program and MATLAB are quite different. Here is an example:

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float c1, c2, c3;
    
    c1 = 1.0e-20;
    c2 = 1.0e-30;
    
    c3 = c1 * c2;
    printf("%e,%e,%e\n",c1,c2,c3);

    return 0;
}
```

The running result is:

```
1.000000e-20,1.000000e-30,0.000000e+00
```

MATLAB program:

```
c1 = 1.0e-20;
c2 = 1.0e-30;
    
c3 = c1 * c2;
fprintf("%e,%e,%e\n",c1,c2,c3);
```

The running result is:

```
1.000000e-20,1.000000e-30,1.000000e-50
```

It is obvious that MATLAB gives the right multiplication result, whereas C gives a wrong result. Could anyone answer why this happens?

In my project, my computation involves such small number computations in C language. Since Matlab can do it correctly, can you give a suggestion how I can also do this in C?

Comment: Try using `double` instead of `float` in the C program.

Comment: Typically, C programs are using [32-bit `float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and [64-bit `double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) values that are using [IEEE-754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), so you might want to read about that.

Comment: @user3386109 is right.  Unless you have special needs and know what you are doing, never use type `float` in C; always use `double`.

Comment: 1e-50 is simply too small for type `float` to represent.  The biggest number you can represent in a `float` is about 1e38, and the smallest is about 1e-45.

Comment: Beware that C (or just about any conventional programming language) has only finite-precision floating point types that are going to have inherently more limitations (both precision and range) as opposed to programs like MATLAB or Mathematica.  You said your work involves "small number computations".  Type `double` will typically give you a useful range of 1e-307 to 1e307 (or down to 1e-324 if you include the subnormals), but if you need better than that, you may need to look into specialized libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most languages, you'll have access to at least two floating-point types: single-precision and double-precision.

In C, `float` is a single-precision float, `double` is a double-precision float.

MATLAB uses `double` by default, but also has `single` for single-precision floats.

If you use `single` values in your MATLAB program, you'll do the same computation that your C program does, with the same result:

```matlab
c1 = single(1.0e-20);
c2 = single(1.0e-30);
c3 = c1 * c2;
fprintf("%e,%e,%e\n",c1,c2,c3);
```

The output is:

```
1.000000e-20,1.000000e-30,0.000000e+00
```

Likewise, you can change your C program to use `double` instead of `float`, to reproduce the MATLAB results exactly.